# Kendo DropDownList validation in Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm revisiting an issue I raised on the Kendo forums (which are now read only). Here's the [original thread](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/inline-edit---validation-not-working-on-dropdownlist.aspx).

The solution proposed by Jon suggests:

> If you pull out the validation message out of the span, it will show up (use jQuery to append it to the parent  element).

I've got the validation working - I just can't get the validation message to display (at least where it's visible). I'm not sure what to append where.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You should append the validation tooltip element `<span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="name"></span>` to the editor container. Where "name" corresponds to the name of your editor input.

Docs:
[columns.editor](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.editor)
[link](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/validator/overview#customizing-the-tooltip-position)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the tip. I thought I'd tried that, but I'd missed off the `data-for=` All is good now.

Comment: @sasheto it's worth putting that as the answer so it can be accepted, this is showing as unanswered.

Comment: @Mat, it's worth copying the question into the Stackoverflow question rather than linking.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the suggestion, I put this as answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should append the validation tooltip element `<span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="name"></span>` to the editor container. Where **"name"** corresponds to the name of your editor input.

Docs: [columns.editor](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/validator/overview#customizing-the-tooltip-position)